# How to process and insert user defined variable from/in SOAP Response/Request i in Jmeter ? SOAP request parametrization in jmeter

Tags: variables, soap, request, response, jmeter

I am trying to solve following problem:
I have a system with which communication is done through SOAP (XML over http).
In Jmeter I am using SOA/XML-RPC (not wsdl based webservice).
I am sending one SOAP request and receiving response in vollowing tag

```
<Prodrevision>5</Prodrevision>
```

This number changes from time to time and goal is to get that number in that tag put it as user defined variable and pass it to another SOAP/XML-RPC

Mine jmeter  test plan looks like that

-User defined variabla - here I have empty varaibla named "var'

-SOAP/XML- RPC (this SOAP REQUEST causes that RESPONSE is received)

<sub>- XPath Extractor with</sub>

```
          reference name: var
          XPath Query: //*[local-name()='Prodrevision']/text()
```

(this should according to FAQ's process/parse response and asssign it to variable var)

-SOAP/XML-RPC - and in this XML request SOAP/XML-RPC data field has

```
..xml data
<Prodrevision>${var}</Prodrevision>
...xml data
```

But I am not sending anything in the second request ??? mine requests hits server but there is no value. 
Where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you see ${variableName} in the request, it means the variable hasn't been defined.  Most likely, it's an issue with how XPath is setup.  I've never used that component, so unfortunately I can't help you there.

However, I've found the post processor Regular Expression Extractor to be very easy and accurate.

The structure would like this:

```
1st Soap Request
  -- regular expression stored to "var"
 2nd Soap Request, using ${var}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been partially solved.
There was an issue in a wrong or badly, for JMeter, defined XPath query

```
      reference name: var
      XPath Query://name[contains(text(),'Prodrevision')]/parent::multiRef/value
```

After the XPath query I have added beanshell postprocessor with following code

```
      print("Beanshell processing  SOAP response");
      print("var" +${var} );
```

So finally I see what value is being grabbed by the XPath extractor.

I have also installed xpather 1.4.5 as a Firefox add-on. And opened XML response and tuned a bit XPath query to have a proper answer. Then this was copied to JMeter and worked.

Next, in SOAP request that had to be sent by JMeter, I have put my XPath extractor value in the following way:

```
<name xsi:type="soapenc:string">Prodrevision</name>
<value xsi:type="soapenc:string">${var}</value>
```

and this again worked well for one thread.

Problem at this moment is with threads. If there is more than 1 (one) thread, it is generating wrong requests :-(